# In what order do piped bash commands execute?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

On Linux (e.g. Ubuntu), if I have a text file, test.txt, with the following contents:

```
one
two
three
```

And I then run the following wc command to count the lines in the file:

```
wc -l test.txt
```

I receive the expected output of:

```
3 test.txt
```

However, when I run the same command, then pipe the output of the wc command to the same filename:

```
wc -l test.txt > test.txt
```

And then cat the file test.txt:

```
cat test.txt
```

I receive the following output, indicating that test.txt now contains 0 lines of data:

```
0 test.txt
```

Shouldn't the wc -l test.txt command process first, then temporarily store the result of that command, then pipe the output to the file?

If it did that, then the second wc -l command should produce the same output as the first one, but it doesn't.

Comment: this is not a pipe, you redirect the standard output to the file. The standard output is opened before starting the program, thus the file gets erase beefore you read it

Comment: mind, if it _were_ a nontrivial pipeline where an early stage did the input and the last stage redirected to the output you'd have a race condition and the order wouldn't be guaranteed (because all pipeline components run in parallel, _theoretically_ the first piece could execute fast enough to start the read before the shell got to the point of setting up the redirection while launching the last piece); but when you have a trivial single-element pipeline there's a firm guarantee that the file is truncated before it's ever read.

Comment: But the **all pipeline components run in parallel** part is the important bit. In `X | Y`, there's no "X happens, then we store the result, then after X is done we feed that result to Y" -- X and Y both get started up at the same time, and as soon as a piece of data is written to X's stdout it's immediately available to Y's stdin. If Y doesn't ever need to read its stdin to operate, it can finish before X is done initializing at all (obviously, commands where that's true don't make much sense to use in pipelines).

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this is not a pipe, but an output redirection.

The redirection is documented as opening `test.txt` for writing (truncating it in the process) *before* `wc` even runs, let alone before `wc` starts to read from the same file. `0` is the expected line count in this case.